# How to know the viewController already visited or not?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I've multiple view controllers in iPhone application, and I'm using navigation controller from starting.

**My question is:** when I am going to the first viewController. Then I go to the second viewController, and then I go back to the first viewController. Here how can I know I have already seen the first view. Means I want to know whether I visited the first viewController or not?

How can I know this? Because I have one functionality in one viewController in which I want that functionality should be run only one time not again and again.

anyone can please help me with this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: just create singleton class and use it to track, since its persist through app's life

Answer (score 1):

There will be stack managed by the UINavigationController of those UIViewController which are currently there in the navigation controller,

As you have not mentioned your language tag, i am posting a code in Objective-c

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++){
    id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]){
       // This view controller is visited by user and currently in the stack
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create an array in app delegate. 
In viewDidload  add an object of current View controller in an Array.
Then finally you can check from array.
If there will be name for a view controller class.
That means user has visited to that class.
As viewdidLoad only calls when user visits a view controller.
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a nsobject:class and a delegate now you can save manually whether you visited that viewController or not.

Or you can send a flag through prepareForSegue method and according to that u can know which is viewed or not

or just create a navigation view controller class check the stack which viewController is last in that array.

Answer (score 0):

You should achieve this.

If you want execute the code the form first viewController only once in application life cycle then maintain a bool flag save it in NSUserDefaults.
More importantly, do this stuff in viewDidLoad of first viewController

See Here

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL isFirstTime = [defaults boolForKey:@"FIRST_TIME"];

    if (isFirstTime == NO)
    {
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FIRST_TIME"];

        //Here Call Your Code
        [self callYourFunctionHere];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}
```